# generating word cloud for items in a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, cpu-word, word-cloud

```
 my_list=["one", "one two", "three"]
```

and I am generating a word cloud for this list by using

```
 wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 1000, height = 500).generate(" ".join(my_list))
```

As I am converting all the items into string it is generating word cloud for

```
   "one","two","three"

 But I want to generate word cloud for the values, "one","one two","three"
```

help me for generating word cloud for items in a list

Answer (score 19, accepted):

one way of doing,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

#convert list to string and generate
unique_string=(" ").join(my_list)
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 1000, height = 500).generate(unique_string)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig("your_file_name"+".png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Another way by creating Counter Dictionary,

```
#convert it to dictionary with values and its occurences
from collections import Counter
word_could_dict=Counter(my_list)
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 1000, height = 500).generate_from_frequencies(word_could_dict)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('yourfile.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WordCloud` takes regular expression as argument. Using this we can make the splitting character a `+` instead of a space.

```
regexp=r"\w[\w' ]+"
```

The list of words then needs to be joined on a `+` as well as each this is now used to split words. Resulting in the following code:

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1000, height=500, regexp=r"\w[\w' ]+").generate("+".join(my_list))
```

Comment: I am getting "KeyError: '"